# How to add text within a block element

Tags: html, css

A very stupid question I'm sure so sorry guys I'm very new to all of this.

I've to put h1-h4 inside four "box" block elements. I've put in h1 right next to the body tag but its showing up outside the box and not in. I've been playing around on sublime and looking it up on google but cant seem to figure out the answer. I know its something so simple yet I'm being so stupid lol

any help would be much appreciated.

**Css**

```
.box { 
display: block; 
width: 100%; 
height: 150px; 
background-color: #81BBC9; 
margin: 10px; 
border-radius: 10px; }
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
 <div id="container">
    <h1>"Header"</h1> 
    <div class="box">
 </div> 
 <div class="box"></div> 
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
<table>
```

Comment: Please share the code too

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to put titles in boxes, put youe box code and insert titles code inqide

Comment: <div><h1>Heading 1</h1></div>
<div><h2>Heading 2</h2></div>
<div><h3>Heading 3</h3></div>
<div><h4>Heading 4</h4></div>

Comment: Hi, how do I share the code? I tried to paste it onto the question but it didn't show all of it

Comment: .box {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 150px;
     background-color: #81BBC9;
     margin: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
 }
 
  </style>
</head>
<body>



  <div id="container">
    <h1>"Header"</h1>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div> 
 <table>
 width: 100%;
 height:200%;

Comment: @Bailey123 - this is your shared code, please edit and add the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asume that "box" means div, so if you want to put some H1, H4 in a div, just make it like this :

```
<div class='myBox'>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <h4>i'm glad to be here</h4>
</div>
```

And to be sure your h1, h4 element are in the div, put the following CSS code :

```
.myBox {
    border: solid 1px orange;
}
```

I hope it could help you.

Comment: Thank you! I had been going crazy! Really appreciate the help. I knew it was something simple. I remember doing this a few months ago, my brain forgot it with learning everything else along the way. :(

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to everyone